# How can I get the label of custom field in shopware 6?

Tags: shopware

I try to get the label of custom field in shopware 6. I already know how to get the technical name.
After various searches, I found this: https://developer.shopware.com/docs/resources/references/adr/2020-09-08-custom-field-label-loading-in-storefront.html
Has anyone already used this? Unfortunately, I don't understand it properly.

Cheers,

Comment: In an app or in a plugin extension?

Comment: This question needs more code. ;-)